# Fetching value of processId from list of process Ids

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am running the below `cmdlet` to get the process ids used by a file:

```
Get-Process | foreach{$processVar = $_;$_.Modules | foreach{if($_.FileName -eq $lockedFile){$processVar.Name + " PID:" + $processVar.id}}}
```

The above cmdlet is generating the output `process1 PID:5260`

Now, I need to pipe the cmdlet so as to kill the above `process id` for which I have written below cmdlet:

```
Get-Process | foreach{$processVar = $_;$_.Modules | foreach{if($_.FileName -eq $lockedFile){$processVar.Name + " PID:" + $processVar.id}}} | Stop-Process $processVar.id
```

However, it is not stopping the process.

I basically want to print out the process name and process id and then kill the process.

The process name and process id are already printing out correctly but need help to pipe the process id into the cmdlet and then kill the process.

Comment: If your first script would output CSV instead of strings this would be easier and safer. Are you up for having the same version updated to output objects instead of strings?

Comment: I basically want to print out the process name and process id and then kill the process

Comment: Move your `Stop-Process` to inside your `If` scriptblock.

Comment: I need help with how to move `stop-process` inside `if`. can you please provide the updated script? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do it this way, I believe outputting an [object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject) to the console  would be more readable. The only change you need to do is move the `Stop-Process` inside the `if` condition.

```
$lockedFile = 'defineThisVariable'
Get-Process | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Modules.FileName.where({$_ -eq $lockedFile})) {
        # This is the ouput object to the console
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Process = $_.Name
            PID     = $_.id
        }
        # Here you stop the Process, you can add
        # `-Verbose` for more output to console
        Stop-Process -Id $_.Id
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. can you please explain what is the use of `pscustomobject`? I have never used the syntax  `[pscustomobject]@`. Do I need to add `write-host pscustomobject` to print out the process id and name on the console?

Comment: @meallhour no, no need to use `write-host`. `pscustomobject` is a nice and easy way to create an object in PowerShell. The script as is, will output an object with 2 properties, `Process` and `PID` to the console. I've edited my answer adding a link to the documentation which is pretty well explained

Comment: the file which I am comparing is on a remote. I am able to connect to remote server using `new-psdrive` however, I am getting error here `FileName.where({$_ -eq \\$server\e$\file.exe}))`  `Unexpected token '\\$server\e$\file.exe' in expression or statement.`

Comment: @meallhour seems like you're missing quotes on that path: `$_ -eq "\\$server\e$\file.exe"`

Comment: It is still not stopping the process on the temporary drive `\\$server\e$\file.exe`. Anything special we need to do for temporary drive?